# Thymeleaf at syntax: "@{/}" returns empty if I include ResourceUrlEncodingFilter

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf.

This template:

```
<a th:href="@{/}">a</a>
```

produces this html:

```
<a href="/">a</a>
```

This is what I'm expected.

I put ResourceUrlEncodingFilter bean to try ContentVersionStrategy in my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter extended class.

```
@Bean
public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter() {
    return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
}
```

The produced html turned to:

```
<a href="">a</a>
```

The value of href is empty.
I hope href is "/" even if I put ResourceUrlEncodingFilter bean.
`th:href="@{/a}"` turns to `href="/a"` in both cases.

Did I do something wrong?

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:

This is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.1.RELEASE'
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart', 'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.1.2.RELEASE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.1')
    compile('org.webjars:knockout:3.2.0')
    compile('org.webjars:momentjs:2.9.0')
    compile('org.webjars:numeral-js:1.5.3-1')
    compile('org.webjars:underscorejs:1.7.0-1')
    compile('org.webjars:sugar:1.4.1')
    compile('org.webjars:jqplot:1.0.8r1250')
    compile('org.webjars:jquery-cookie:1.4.1-1')

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context-support")               //  this is for mail

    compile('commons-codec:commons-codec')
    compile("commons-io:commons-io")
    compile('com.google.guava:guava')
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-validator')
    compile("com.sun.mail:javax.mail")
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compile("org.yaml:snakeyaml")

    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.2")
    compile('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.9.4')
    compile('net.sf.supercsv:super-csv:2.2.0')
    compile('edu.vt.middleware:vt-password:3.1.2')
}

test {
    //systemProperties 'property': 'value'
    systemProperties 'spring.profiles.active':  'unittest'
    systemProperties 'MAIL_PROP':               'mail.properties'
    systemProperties 'user.timezone':           'UTC'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: which spring version are you using? could you share your Webconfig/web.xml? are you using plain Spring Framework or Spring Boot?

Comment: I'm using io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.1.2.RELEASE with gradle. It will include spring-webmvc 4.1.6.RELEASE. I can show my build.gradle. Thanks for your replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for this detailed explanation and the repro project!

This is actually a bug: see [SPR-13241](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13241), to be fixed in Spring 4.1.8 and 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot adds "/**" matcher for automatic configurations of static web resources locations.
The locations are /META-INF/resources/, /resources/, /static/ and /public/.

When you put below html in Thymeleaf template,

```
<a th:href="@{/}">a</a>
```

Below method in [ResourceUrlProvider.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.1.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceUrlProvider.java) is called because of the matcher and get into for loop:

```
public final String getForLookupPath(String lookupPath) {
        // -- omission --
        for(String pattern : matchingPatterns) {
            // -- omission --
            String pathWithinMapping = getPathMatcher().extractPathWithinPattern(pattern, lookupPath);
            String pathMapping = lookupPath.substring(0, lookupPath.indexOf(pathWithinMapping));
            // -- omission --
            String resolved = chain.resolveUrlPath(pathWithinMapping, handler.getLocations());
            if (resolved == null) {
                continue;
            }
            // -- omission --
            return pathMapping + resolved;

        }
        // -- omission --
}
```

The argument, lookupPath is "/" by the "@{/}", Then:

- The pathWithinMapping will be "".
- The pathMapping will be "".
- The resolved will be "".

So this method returns "" and the value is set to href="".

This is in my opinion, if the pathWithinMapping is "", to continue the for loop seems good. Calling  chain.resolveUrlPath seems not good.

Thanks,

Comment: To bypass this, I'm using "@{/./}" instead of "@{/}". Logically equivalent.

Comment: In this case, the resource should not be marked as being readable and should return null - see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/cbe4a49b54c56258da0fb419486ad9615d7b70ce/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/PathResourceResolver.java#L122

Comment: I've created a sample repro project that shows how this works out for me: https://gist.github.com/bclozel/359baafbbb162b19311b
Could you share your WebConfig here? Maybe there's something special about your resource locations or the servlet container you're using? This may be a bug in the Spring Framework. Thanks

Comment: I challenged to reproduce with your gist but I couldn't reproduce neither. So I removed bunch of codes in my actual project repeatedly, webjar triggered the matters. I created the repository put together the essence:  https://github.com/quwahara/stackoverflow-questions-31182261 Thanks for help!